# Trying to build HOC to wrap around Signin, Why do I keep getting this error? on /signin route?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Error is: 
"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

I dont see any mistakes, Appreciate your help!

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NavWrapper from "./NavWrapper";

const Home = lazy(() => import("./Home"));

const Signin = lazy(() => import("./Signin"));

const App = () => {
  const navWrapper = (component, props) => (
    <NavWrapper component={component} {...props} />
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
            <Route
              path="/signin"
              component={props => navWrapper({ ...props }, Signin)}
              exact
            />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

// .......in NavWrapper

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const NavWrapper = ({ component: Component, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Test...</div>}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavWrapper;
```

//..in Signin

```
import React from "react";
const Signin = () => {
  return <div>Testing</div>;
};

export default Signin;
```

Comment: Well for one, you swapped the parameters (component, props) of your wrapper in your Route where you pass (props, component).

Answer (score 0):

You swapped the parameters of your navWrapper HOC function.

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"; 
import NavWrapper from "./NavWrapper"; 

const Home = lazy(() => import("./Home")); 
const Signin = lazy(() => import("./Signin")); 

const App = () => {
  // Note the parameter order of navWrapper
  const navWrapper = (component, props) => (
    <NavWrapper component={component} {...props} />
  ); 

  return ( 
    <div> 
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}> 
          <Switch> 
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact /> 
            <Route 
              path="/signin" 
              component={props => navWrapper(Signin, { ...props })} // ensure parameters same order
              exact
            /> 
          </Switch> 
        </Suspense> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div> 
  ); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

component={props => navWrapper({ ...props }, Signin)}

should be:

component={props => navWrapper(Signin, { ...props })}

because your function declaration is:

const navWrapper = (component, props) => (...);

no?